# Starting AlertDialog fragment from MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-alertdialog, android-fragmentactivity

I'm sure there is a simple answer for this. I'm trying to start an AlertDialogFragment (RegForXapo) from my main activity without a button. It pops up but app force closes when i click the positive or negative button.

Here is my main

```
sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(mypref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPref.getBoolean("firstRun", true)) {
        //start AlertDialog
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        RegForXapo reg = new RegForXapo();
fm.show(reg, "dialog");
    }
```

Here is my dialog

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.*;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;


 import android.content.*;public class RegForXapo extends DialogFragment
 {
    private Context context;

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.xapoask);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.positivebutton, 
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //dismiss dialog and set to never appear. take user to xapo reg
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("MySharedPrefs",0);
            Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("firstRun",false);
            Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URL));
            startActivity(launchBrowser);

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.negativebutton, 
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //dismiss dialog and set to never appear
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("MySharedPrefs",0);
            Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("firstRun",false);

        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton(R.string.neutralbutton,
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //dismiss dialog and set to reappear
            // no code necesary
        }


    });


    return builder.create();
}

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a RegForXapo (DialogFragment) object, and then `show` it.

```
sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(mypref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if (sharedPref.getBoolean("firstRun", true)) {
    //start AlertDialog
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    RegForXapo regForXapo = new RegForXapo();
    regForXapo.show(fm, "dialog");
}
```

Comment: Now getting error no applicable method to (android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, during)..

Comment: Try `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Changed FragmentManager fm to android.app.FragmentManager fm... It works now. But i get force close when clicking the negative or positive button.

Comment: Got cat log downloaded. It's a issue with sharedPrefs in my dialog class. Can you help or should i create a new question since my original question is technically answered.

Comment: I suggest creating a new question! You can then post the link here and tag me, and I'll check it out.